# Problems with deploying Kohana to a cloud machine - 404

Tags: php, apache, deployment, kohana

I have uploaded all my project files onto my cloud machine in the drectory `/var/www/html/`. 
When I visit the IP address of this machine through a browser, it shows me the expected page, which routes to `MyCtrl/index`. 
However, if I manually go to `IPAddr/MyCtrl/index`, I get an apache server 404 error.
None of the other routes work either. eg. `IPAddr/MyCtrl/someOtherAction` results in a 404 as well.

The fact that the homepage loads means that the default configuration for `MyCtrl/index` is working, but maybe URL rewriting is not being done right?
Can someone tell me whether the problem is with my `bootstrap.php` file or with my `.htaccess` file, along with a possible fix?
It's the first time I'm deplying an application onto a cloud machine, so I'm not really sure what the problem is.

Comment: It's seems that the problem in your Rotes. Can you show them?

Comment: There was no problem with the routes, the Apache server on the cloud machine was incorrectly configured, I have posted what fixed my problem as an answer below. Thank you though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if anyone has the same issue, here's the fix:
(This is considering that all project files are in `/var/www/html/`

Changes have to be made in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

From:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

To:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options All
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

This answer helped me out:
[Kohana The requested URL /home was not found on this server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26003826/kohana-the-requested-url-home-was-not-found-on-this-server)